# Should the AC-Live or AC-Neutral wire be 'broken' by a relay?

Tags: ac, relay

I have a 230VAC relay that will switch my bathroom light as well as the extractor fan. The question I have is whether the Live/Phase wire or the Nutral wire go through the relay?

Comment: Think about what happens if you switch the bulb and accidentally touch any of the contacts while the relay is "off" in either situation.

Comment: Also, take a look at how light switches are wired.  You will want to wire your relay in a similar way for the same reasons.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was thinking but i saw a lot of illustrations on the internet where the neutral wire goes through the relay.

Comment: *"I found it on the internet"* is no excuse for much of anything, and *certainly* not for how to properly set up safety-critical systems.  This really should be obvious.

Comment: You could break both. Then there is no question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Well, to be fair, your advice is from the internet, too... Surely you don't mean that no-one can trust anything found anywhere on the internet?

Comment: trust no one. and learn to read standards and trust your experience

Comment: Or maybe _"learn the reasons behind the standards"_ so you're not just blindly following anyone's advice, internet or otherwise?

Comment: Yes, my advice here is just on the internet too.  That's why I try to explain the "why" behind the answer, not just dump a "do this" on you.  Ultimately it's your responsibility to vet anything you are told here.  That said, Stack Exchange is better than some random place on the internet exactly because it is vetted by a large number of people via the voting mechanism.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Although I understand and maybe agree with your point of view not using a double pole connection. It could be difficult to convince an insurance company if something goes wrong and they found it is not installed according the  electrical code.

Comment: @Dec: I never said to use only a single pole switch if the electrical code specifies double pole.  Of course do whatever the electrical code says, which is also what I said in the first sentence of my answer.  Most electrical codes only require any hot lines (which there is only one of in this case) to be switched.  That is certainly the case in the US where I live.  If your electrical code requires both to be switched, then by all means follow it.

Comment: @Olin: Point taken. To comply in the Netherlands with the code for bathroom installations makes it very difficult to play around with more than standard material.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, in my country, NZ, if one is reasonably competent in domestic electrical stuff, they can do whatever they like, as long as it doesn't touch the switchboard, that part of it is reserved for an electrician. 

This is the way it should be too. It's not that hard but unfortunately as you try to learn it you come across more people arguing that if you don't know you shouldn't be doing it, rather than just answering the question. 

This is what people are trying to do by asking these questions, improve their competency.

Answer (score 13):

Surely this is specified in whatever electrical code applies to your jurisdiction.

**Put the switch in the hot line, not the neutral.**

Even without the electrical code, a few seconds thought should have revealed the answer too.  Purely from the device's point of view, it doesn't matter since the device and switch are in series.  The switch in the neutral line will work correctly.

However, consider the voltage the device will be at in both cases.  With the hot line open, the whole device is at the neutral potential.  With the neutral line open, the whole device is at line potential.  This isn't *supposed to* matter, but stuff happens.  With a lot of moisture around, for example, external surfaces could be connected to line voltage thru the moisture leakage path when the neutral line is open but the hot line not.

In cases where there are two hot lines going to a device, like 240 V devices in the US, you should be switching both of them.  There are ganged switches (DPST) just for this purpose.  This doesn't apply to something low power like a bathroom light and fan.  I only mention it for completeness and to better illustrate the point.

Comment: I live in the Netherlands. The electrical code leaves it open how to switch electricity in a bathroom. |In Belgium however the use of a double pole light switch in the bathroom is mandatory.

Comment: The Belgian engineers must have a good reason for this. It's probably why they have more beer selection than the Dutch too...

Comment: @Decapod notice that it is not required anymore to have double pole light switch anymore. 

Source: just built a house.

Comment: @Snake: Please publish a link to the source and a link to the changed regulations

Comment: @Decapod (Dutch) http://www.livios.be/nl/bouwinformatie/techniek/elektriciteit/vraag/8907/enkelpolige-schakelaars-op-badkamer/

Answer (score 3):

The norm DIN VDE 0100-460 states that a SPST switch must not be placed in the neutral path.
The norm DIN VDE 0100-470 adds that a DPST switch that switches both neutral and phase must have a lagging pole for neutral during switch OFF and a leading pole during switch ON.

You should check whether there is a similar norm for your country.

Comment: Would the rule about DPST apply to directly-mechanically-operated switches which lack a mechanism to ensure both poles switch together, or does it imply some minimum lag between operations?  Does it include fail-safety requirements (e.g. there must be no plausible means by which the "fixed" hot contact could fail shorted while the neutral contact is opened)?

Comment: @supercat:

The switching points of both poles must be slightly offset to ensure that neutral is contacted first during switch ON and last during switch OFF.

I don't know whether the mechanism has to be fail-safe.

Answer (score 1):

It is more safe to use a DPST relais. So switch both line and neutral. But remember the electrical code in your area could be different.

There is however more. Where are you going to place the relais and how are you going to install the wiring. The installation should not become wett. Unless it is allowed by the protection level.

Remember the bathroom is a wet area where specific rules for the installation apply. So must all metal parts in the bathroom be connected to earth and the breaker is most probably a so called earth leakage breaker or RCD.

Since you are living in the Netherlands.The NEN 1010 electrical code applies.
The bathroom is divided into zones each with their own requirements. 230V outlets are not allowed and the bathroom electricity system must be protected with an RCD. So it all depends where you want to place your relay.

Comment: The English term is probably "RCD" (in the UK) or "GFCI" (in the USA). They do the same job but meet different, incompatible, national standards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only switching one leg, it should definitely be the HOT wire. Suppose you have a lamp and there's a problem with one of the socket contacts. Maybe it's bent down and won't contact the bulb anymore (I have had this problem). You turn off the lamp, take out the bulb, and reach in to pull the tab contact up a bit. POW! You get a zap. The device still has power even when the switch is off if you're only switching the neutral line. You should ALWAYS break the hot line, and as mentioned it would be even better if you switch both of them.

Comment: If you deliberately touch the contacts without turning off the whole circuit *and checking* you're too trusting.  In your case I'd have isolated it at the fuse box/consumer unit, then either tested with a multimeter or adjusted with an insulated tool.

Comment: @ChrisH Sure, any experienced person should know to test it before touching it, but we know that there are millions of inexperienced people who to probing around in the socket without conducting the proper tests. Having the switch on the neutral line vs. on the hot line is a good way to get an inexperienced person killed